# Is there something using which i can write the code in jsp, and run it as standalone program?

Tags: apache-flex

Is it possible to code as if you are coding for any web application [ use html, jsp, css, spring etc ], but on execution it should not require any container or any server. It should run as if we are running a swing application.

*Somebody told me that Adobe Flex is just what i am asking for. Is it so?*

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/). It lets you define the user interface using a markup language called [MXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML) and compiles it in to a desktop application that is platform independent. Though AIR uses the [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/coding_with_mxml_and_actionscript/) framework, it has additional classes that allows you to interact with the desktop environment (file handling, window management etc).

AIR is platform independent - you can run an AIR application on any platform that has AIR environment installed in it (just like you need to install java to run a java app).

Here is a sample AIR code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    title="App Title" width="400" height="200" 
    creationComplete="someFunction()">
    <mx:TextInput id="ti"/>
    <mx:Button id="btn" label="Click Me!" click="onClick();"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function someFunction():void
            {
                ti.text = "Application created!";
                //do initialization stuff here
            }
            private function onClick():void
            {
                ti.text = "You clicked me!"
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```